# How to add dynamic events for view?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

How can I add dynamic events in my view class in Backbone.js

I have a View Class with

```
var myViewClass = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'change select': 'changeSelect',
        'click a.changeLink': 'clearSelect'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.delegateEvents({'click select': 'changeSelect'});
    },

    .
    .
    .        
});
```

This is adding {'click select': 'changeSelect'} event, however somehow {'click a.changeLink': 'clearSelect'} doesn't woek.

anybody knows the solution?

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Can you show the html for the anchor tag with the class changeLink?  And also perhaps the method, clearSelect?

Comment: By passing in events in delegateEvents, I believe you are overriding the events property, thus they would no longer work.  Its not clear what you are trying to do here.  Why not put all your events in one place in the events hash?  As in, why the need to add that specific event selector via the delegateEvents function call?

Comment: @Bill you are right, the second instruction in delegateEvents is `$(this.el).unbind();`.  It looks like Rohan should not call delegateEvents at all.  Declaring the events object should be sufficient.

Answer (score 19):

Backbone automatically delegates events from the events attribute of your view. You are overrriding the previously delegated events. You can call $(this.el).delegate(...) but you can also do

```
this.delegateEvents(_.extend(this.events, {'click select': 'changeSelect'}));
```

Comment: This is pretty easy, but I wonder why there isn't a built-in function for this.

Comment: If you are extending a view, you actually have to ```_.clone(this.events)``` or it will fail if you don't have ```changeSelect``` in the original view. Tricky. ```this.delegateEvents(_.extend(_.clone(this.events), {'click select': 'changeSelect'}));```

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm doing this a lot, here is my tiny Backbone extension (based on Julien's answer and my testing):

```
Backbone.View.prototype.addEvents = function(events) {
  this.delegateEvents( _.extend(_.clone(this.events), events) );
};
```

Use:

```
BaseResizable.View = Base.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    Base.View.prototype.initialize.call(this);
    this.addEvents({
      'resizestop': 'resizeStop'
    });
  },
  resizeStop: function(event, ui){...}
}
```

You will have to do `addEvents()` again if you use `undelegateEvents()`.